# Drop down menu gets weird position

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, position

Here's the code for my toolbar:

```css
.toolbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #252525;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
}

.centered_toolbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.toolbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.toolbar li {
  float: left;
}

.toolbar a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.toolbar a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.dropdown a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="centered_toolbar">
    <img src="./logo.png" width="200px" height="auto" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; margin-left: 30px;">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a a href='#' onclick="goToMainPage()"><i class="dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a a href='#' onclick="goToNoteslistPage()"><i class="notenliste"></i>Notenliste</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href='#' onclick="myFunction()" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin-right: 120px;">

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
                          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </a>
    <a href='#' onclick="logout()" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin-right: 20px; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;"><i
                            class="logout"></i>Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is best described through the following image:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt47iz5r5fhjrss/bug.PNG?dl=0
The drop down menu is not under the drop down button. And not only that. With that code, the Drop down button himself gets lower than the other elements in the toolbar. Can please help me anyone out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

Your HTML layout was a little messy, you needed to include your dropdown within your `ul` `li` list with the other items. I have amended your HTML and CSS below.

```css
.toolbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #252525;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
}

.centered_toolbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.toolbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.toolbar li {
  float: left;
}

.toolbar a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.toolbar a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.dropdown a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="centered_toolbar">
    <img src="./logo.png" width="200px" height="auto">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href='#' onclick="goToMainPage()"><i class="dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' onclick="goToNoteslistPage()"><i class="notenliste"></i>Notenliste</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href='#' onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href='#' onclick="logout()"><i class="logout"></i>Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

With further inspection, I have amended my answer with:

I have removed `position:absolute` from the logo image and the logout button and used `justify-content:space-between` on the container. This is a cleaner way to get your menu items to be spaced equally.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Can you please have look at this image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt47iz5r5fhjrss/bug.PNG?dl=0  With your code the ul elements are no longer centered in the middle of the toolbar.

Comment: @FilipDegenhart Ah I see what you mean! I have amended the HTML and CSS again, and removed the in-line style (you should try and always keep your style separate from HTML in future). I have removed `position: absolute` on your logo and logout buttons and added `justify-content: space-between` to the container. This is a better way of spacing out your items :-)

Answer (score 1):

If this is your requirement then you can remove the position attribute. The position attribute is shifting your button but the drop down values are not shifting the position based on your position attribute.

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to include the actual code so the OP can take it.

Comment: it would be helpful if he understand the **logic** rather than **copying and pasting the code** @coops

Comment: Or you could do both :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to some error in setting the  CSS. You can use bootstrap templates for your help.
[See if this helps](https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, as links can get obsolete. Try to update your answer with the essential part of what you found useful in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

I would avoid to put any inline CSS unless you HAVE TO, it makes code really hard to maintain as your project grows. In your case, `position: absolute` are not necessary either.

```css
.toolbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #252525;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.toolbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.toolbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.toolbar a,
.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.toolbar a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}

.dropdown a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./logo.png" width="100px" height="auto">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <a a href='#' onclick="goToMainPage()"><i class="dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li><a a href='#' onclick="goToNoteslistPage()"><i class="notenliste"></i>Notenliste</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#' onclick="logout()">
        <i class="logout"></i>Logout
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but the logout is not at the right anymore. Even the image is not at the left. How to fix?